# How to keep intersect value after a Undo in variable

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save the result of the intersect function in a variable on the change of my form. Then do a Undo to record the old values of the same location with the intersect function in order to have the old and new values in variables

I tried to save the result in a global variable but it doesn't change anything

```vb
Dim oldValues As Variant
Dim vNew As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Targets As Range)
    'vNew = "new value"
    Set vNew = Intersect(Targets, Targets.Parent.UsedRange)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'MsgBox return the new value
    MsgBox vNew(1)
    Application.Undo
    'MsgBox return the old value when I want to save the new for later and I 
    'haven't reassigned my variable
    MsgBox "Vnew After undo " & vNew(1)
    Set vOld = Intersect(Targets, Targets.Parent.UsedRange)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Currently the variable vNew is modified by the old value after the undo. While I'm not reassigning my variable. I think it's because the Intersect function is restarted when the variable is called. How to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things: Careful with the Worksheets_Change event as you can easily create endless loops. Secondly, use "option explicit" in the beginning of your modules. vOld is not declared (is that supposed to your "oldValues" variable?).

Here is an idea how to achieve what you want:
1. Save all values in your worksheet in a global dictionary
2. Update the value whenever it is changed (and interact with the old value if you want)

Create a module with this code

```
Public dicOldValues As New Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub InitializeValues()

    Dim rngCell As Range

    ' Save all values of non empty cells
    For Each rngCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTable")
        If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
            dicOldValues.Add rngCell.Address, rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateValue(rngTargets As Range)

    Dim rngSelected As Range

    ' Get selected cell
    Set rngSelected = Intersect(rngTargets, rngTargets.Parent.UsedRange)

    'MsgBox return the new value
    MsgBox "New value: " & rngSelected.Value

    ' Print out old value if it exists
    If dicOldValues.Exists(rngSelected.Address) Then
        MsgBox "Old value for this cell: " & dicOldValues.Item(rngSelected.Address)
        ' Save new value
        dicOldValues.Item(rngSelected.Address) = rngSelected.Value
    Else
        dicOldValues.Add rngSelected.Address, rngSelected.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

When you open your workbook (or whenever you deem necessary), get all initial values:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Modul2.InitializeValues
End Sub
```

Call the update function on your worksheet change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Targets As Range)

    Call Modul2.UpdateValue(Targets)

End Sub
```

There are probably still a few issues with this (for one, depending on the size of your worksheets and the horrible use of a global variable, this might get rather memory heavy) but it should get you along.

Edit: To use the scripting.dictionary you have to check the reference to the Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime library. Alternatively you can use 
    CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")